# R Foreach behavior different in Windows and Linux

Tags: windows, r, foreach, parallel-processing, redhat

My R script which uses libraries doSNOW and foreach to run a process in parallel. This script works properly and uses all cores available in a Windows 7 machine( 4 cores in my case). but when it runs on a Linux (redhat) machine which has 24 cores it makes use of only 3 cores. is there anything I have to take care in the R script while running on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably got a hard-coded `makeCluster(3)` in your startup code. Change it to `makeCluster(detectCores())` or `makeCluster(detectCores()-1)`. (The -1 is so you'll always have a spare core for other tasks.)

Comment: "detectCores()" thats what I was missing.. :) Thanks You.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the parallel backend doMC in Linux.